# What could this OP_RETURN value be

Tags: transactions, address, op-return

I was messing around on the blockchain learning about OP_RETURN outputs and the equivalent use of Input Data in Ethereum and came across something interesting and I can't make sense of it.

It starts with a ETH transaction:

`0xd304e780755f46e62a42884421e39af06342f0a4989704ee02989043769c4f93`

When decoded, the input data mentions a Bitcoin address:

`bc1q0rggj4h837qcldhv8hwxpva32nf645excexqq2`

When I looked at this Bitcoin address I noticed the following transaction:

`444a6542a01d6ce10c9fe01e323447fcf73047b78d8de10a05fa14243233a3a2`

Based on the timing and values in the ETH and BTC transactions I figured this was some kind of coin exchange (they were swapping ETH for BTC) which I thought was rather neat as I never thought of using OP_RETURN in this way. But then I noticed that in the Bitcoin transaction above we have another OP_RETURN output which decodes to:

`OUT:D304E780755F46E62A42884421E39AF06342F0A4989704EE02989043769C4F93`  <-- there is a space on the end

First I thought this might be a Doge Coin address as it starts with "D" but it is too long and now my curiosity has the better of me. Does anyone know what that D304... might be?

Comment: could be a Thorchain memo https://dev.thorchain.org/protocol-development/chain-clients/utxo.html?highlight=op_return#utxo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decoded OP_RETURN output

```
OUT:D304E780755F46E62A42884421E39AF06342F0A4989704EE02989043769C4F93
```

matches the transaction identifier of the Ethereum transaction you mention first

```
0xd304e780755f46e62a42884421e39af06342f0a4989704ee02989043769c4f93
```

Comment: Don't know how I didn't see that. I got so hung up on it being a hex encoding and trying to decode it.